# Django gives Seg Fault when rendering template, but works with pdb

Tags: django, python-3.x, segmentation-fault

So I'm working on this webapp, and it was working smoothly until I started adding Translations to it.

Now, when I request a specific URL in my template, it gives ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE in the browser, and the terminal shows Seg Fault.

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
October 18, 2018 - 21:25:00
Django version 2.1, using settings 'Inovatoxin.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
[18/Oct/2018 21:25:02] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 53144
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

The function that causes this is absolutely simple (and I know that the program actually reaches that view):

```
def about(request):
    """
    Shows detail page for the project.
    """
    return render(request, 'Proteins/about.html', {})
```

So I naturally though the problem is somewhere in rendering the template, and decided to debug it with pdb. I then changed the function above to this:

```
def about(request):
"""
Shows detail page for the project.
"""
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
return render(request, 'Proteins/about.html', {})
```

But when I run the server the error disappears, and the page renders correctly in the browser, translated, even:

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
October 18, 2018 - 21:20:25
Django version 2.1, using settings 'Inovatoxin.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
[18/Oct/2018 21:20:27] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 53144
> /home/gguidini/UnB/InovaToxin/Inovatoxin/Proteins/views.py(83)about()
-> return render(request, 'Proteins/about.html', {})
(Pdb) c
[18/Oct/2018 21:20:32] "GET /about/ HTTP/1.1" 200 15873
```

I quite don't know what's going on here. How can I debug an error that disappears with the debugger? And what could be causing that Seg Fault?

**DETAILS:**
Using Django 2.1, Python 3.7.0 in a Manjaro Linux.

**EDIT**

I was suggested (by a Django Telegram group member) that it could be a corrupted file or a problem with my environment.

So I recompilled the translation messages, because the issue appeared after adding them, and the problem persisted.

I also tried in a different machine and the problem was gone. so **it's an environment problem**, but I don't know what problem it is.

Comment: I am having a very similar problem. Everything fine on development and production. They we made the production server public and any time the template needs to render a form, i get a seg fault with minimal error messages.